# creating bash script to automate task for analyzing multiple files

Tags: linux, bash, shell, loops

I don't have a lot of experience with scripting.

I have a directory that contains, among many other files, a set of `*.phylip` files I need to analyze with a program. I would like to automate this task. I think a loop bash shell script would be appropriate, although I could be wrong.

If I was to perform the analysis manually on one `.phylip` file, I would use the following command in terminal:

```
./raxmlHPC-SSE3 -m GTRCAT -y -s uce-5.phylip --print-identical-sequences -p 12345 -n uce-5_result
```

For the bash shell script, I think it would be close to:

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in $( ls ); do
    ./raxmlHPC-SSE3 -m GTRCAT -y -s uce-5.phylip --print-identical-sequences -p 12345 -n test_5 $i
done
```

The issue I'm aware of, but don't know how to fix, is the -s option, which specifies the input phylip file. Any suggestions on how to modify the script to do what I need done?

Comment: Never parse ls output, refer http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29 page for Bash Pitfalls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in *.phylip
do
    ./raxmlHPC-SSE3 -m GTRCAT -y -s "$i" --print-identical-sequences -p 12345 -n ${i%.phylip}_result
done
```

`-s` option will be passed `$i` which has the file name with `.phylip` extension in the current directory.

`${i%.phylip}_result` replaces the `.phylip` extension with `_result` which i guess is what you expect. (Ref: [Parameter Substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html#PARAMSUBREF))